# php OCI8 install on docker

Tags: php, oracle, docker

Hello I have a really simple dockerfile who is the following:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

ARG URL_INSTALL_CLIENT_BASIC='https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2110000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.10.0.0.0dbru.zip'
ARG URL_INSTALL_CLIENT_SDK='https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2110000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.10.0.0.0dbru.zip'

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt install -y unzip curl

RUN mkdir /opt/oracle
RUN curl ${URL_INSTALL_CLIENT_BASIC} --output /opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.zip
RUN curl ${URL_INSTALL_CLIENT_SDK} --output /opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.zip
RUN unzip '/opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.zip' -d /opt/oracle
RUN unzip '/opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.zip' -d /opt/oracle
RUN rm /opt/oracle/instantclient-*.zip
RUN mv /opt/oracle/instantclient_* /opt/oracle/instantclient
RUN docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient
RUN docker-php-ext-install oci8
RUN echo /opt/oracle/instantclient/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-insantclient.conf
RUN ldconfig
```

I have been through the documentation to see how install it. I followed it exactly.

When I build the docker image `docker build . -t mytest` no error

but when I check extensions OCI8 is missing `docker run mytest:latest php -m`.

I have this nice warning

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/oci8.so (libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/oci8.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/oci8.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
...
```

do you have any idea what I missed ?

Thank you

PS @Paul W:
The following command `docker run mytest:latest ls -la /opt/oracle/instantclient` provide me this result. This is like the `lib` folder I guess:

```
total 245440
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      4096 Oct 18 12:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      4096 Oct 18 12:03 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      5780 Jun 28  2022 BASIC_LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      1631 Jun 28  2022 BASIC_README
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      5780 Jun 28  2022 SDK_LICENSE
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root      1625 Jun 28  2022 SDK_README
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     42160 Jun 28  2022 adrci
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     59536 Jun 28  2022 genezi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 Oct 18 12:03 libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.21.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 Oct 18 12:03 libclntsh.so.10.1 -> libclntsh.so.21.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 Oct 18 12:03 libclntsh.so.11.1 -> libclntsh.so.21.1
...
```

PS2 @Paul W:
what is really weird is if I follow the warning, this file is missing `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/oci8.so` but it' exist and every body can read it ....

But it's exist :

```
docker run mytest:latest ls -la /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/oci8.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 192664 Oct 18 12:03 /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/oci8.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see it into the doc, but apparently oracle has more dependencies ...

If I install this the dockerfile now works without warning

`libaio1`

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

ARG URL_INSTALL_CLIENT_BASIC='https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/217000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.7.0.0.0dbru.zip'
ARG URL_INSTALL_CLIENT_SDK='https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/217000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.7.0.0.0dbru.zip'

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt install -y unzip curl libaio1

RUN mkdir /opt/oracle
RUN curl ${URL_INSTALL_CLIENT_BASIC} --output /opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.zip
RUN curl ${URL_INSTALL_CLIENT_SDK} --output /opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.zip
RUN unzip '/opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.zip' -d /opt/oracle
RUN unzip '/opt/oracle/instantclient-sdk-linux.zip' -d /opt/oracle
RUN rm /opt/oracle/instantclient-*.zip
RUN mv /opt/oracle/instantclient_* /opt/oracle/instantclient
RUN docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient
RUN docker-php-ext-install oci8
RUN echo /opt/oracle/instantclient/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-insantclient.conf
RUN ldconfig
```